# StringFormat doesn't format date (string data type) inside Data Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, date-formatting

StringFormat not seems to be working when formatting date. Column TransactionTime is in string format and i like to format it to 'MM/dd/yyyy' but grid always shows actual value

'2018-09-12 08:14:51'

I have tried using text block and DataGridTextColumn but no luck.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Date"  Width="auto" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding  Path=TransactionTime,StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yy HH:mm}',ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"></DataGridTextColumn>


 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Transaction Time">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransactionTime, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `TransactionTime`?

Comment: Its string.................

Comment: Why are you trying to format a **string** as `MM/dd/yyyy`. Should `TransactionTime` perhaps instead be `DateTime`?

Comment: The StringFormat of a Binding is ignored when the source property already is a string.

Comment: @user1263981 Why are you so desperate to hold this date value as a string? DateTime data, like numbers, should be held in their native format and only converted to strings at the point they're going to be displayed to the user.

Comment: Value is coming from API in List of object and its format is string. I am going to try and see if it be changed to date time before binding a Data Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringFormats` are not applied to `string` properties.

You should either change the type of the source property to `DateTime`, return an already formatted `string` from the `TransactionType` property, or add a new property that returns a formatted date and bind to this one:

```
public string FormattedtTransactionTime
{
    get
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TransactionTime)
            && DateTime.TryParseExact(TransactionTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to convert string to date time inside data grid?

Answer (score -2):

Try changing `StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"` to `StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy"` or check if Data Grid Column has `DataFormatString` property, if it does, set format there as follows:

`DataFormatString={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"`